# BCM issue - car won't completely shut down

Tags: bcm, holden

I have a Holden Calais Sports wagon and when I turn the ignition off and open the door the radio does not turn off. I have to open and close the door several times (sometimes lots of times) before the radio turns off. I can turn the radio off manually but the display still stays on and never turns off.
looking through Google I think the issue might be BCM - Body Control Module. Has anyone else experienced this issue.
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked to ensure the door switch is functioning correctly? If the switch doesn't register and never tells the BCM the door has opened, it won't cut the power to the radio and other powered accessories. Be a good place to start. On most cars, it will also register the passenger side just like the driver's ... you could test it by opening that door and see if the BCM is behaving correctly.